# el is undefined when event fires

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I trigger an event from one view like this:

```
select: function () {
    // Shorthand for the application namespace
    var app = brickpile.app;
    // Trigger the selected event
    app.trigger('selected', this.model);
}
```

and binds to the same event in another view:

```
initialize: function () {
    // Shorthand for the application namespace
    var app = brickpile.app;
    // bind to the selected event
    app.bind('selected', this.selected);
},
```

in my function I get the current instance el property?

```
selected: function (model) {
    // find the input hidden located in this views el
    $(this.el)... // is undefined
},
```

what have I missed?

Comment: Probably a scope problem, try app.bind('selected', this.selected, this);

Comment: You could also `_.bindAll(this, 'selected')` in your `initialize` and not worry about the context argument to `bind`.

Comment: @nikoshr - please provide answers as answers instead of comments

Comment: @DerickBailey Typing a full blown answer on a virtual keyboard setup in french on a telephone screen can be tricky :) Here's my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll quote [Backbone FAQ](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this) to answer your question

> **Binding "this"**
>
> Perhaps the single most common JavaScript "gotcha" is the fact that when you pass a function as a callback, its
> value for this is lost. With Backbone, when dealing with events and
> callbacks, you'll often find it useful to rely on _.bind and _.bindAll
> from Underscore.js.
>
> When binding callbacks to Backbone events, you can choose to pass an
> optional third argument to specify the this that will be used when the
> callback is later invoked.

Try

```
app.bind('selected', this.selected, this);
```

or

```
_.bindAll(this, 'selected');
app.bind('selected', this.selected);
```